# Control of the accreditation of investors

Tags: contract-development

If it is necessary, that the smart contract should distribute tokens only to the accredited investors. To do this, the smart contract must contain a list of accredited investors, as well as update it as new information becomes available. Tell me, please, does the Ethereum platform allow for such functionality in smart contracts?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, Ethereum platform has all the functionality you need.** 
 Your token contract can have a list of all the accredited investors. 
 When new data appears you can just call method of smart contract to update list of investors. 
 Have a look at [this example](https://etherscan.io/token/EOS#balances). This is ERC20 token smart-contract. Read about its functionality [here](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md) or [here](https://www.ethereum.org/token). 
 But this doesnt mean you can't build your own smart contract. You can implement many ideas with Ethereum platform, just be sure to pay enough attention to security.